# g:select value disappears after populating the select

Tags: grails, gsp

Im using g:select to that is populated with a list from controller!
i pass the selected value as well from the controller when the select changed and submitted !

```
 <g:select id="select"
           name="select"
           from="${someList}"
           value="${passedParameter_selectedValue}"
           noSelection="${['':'sth']}"
           optionValue='name'
           optionKey="id"
           />
```

When i debugged it so after submitting the values , my page is refreshed with a list from the controller! so the select has ( Value ) after one iteration then it becomes null !

The thing is it was working good when i didn't use optionKey!

Comment: value should be same as optionKey e.g. your optionKey is an `id` and therefore `value` should also be an id of the instance, try  `value="${passedParameter?.id}"`

Comment: please add the relevant parts from the controller.

Comment: Thanks alot ! it was it that the value should be the same as optionKey ! post it so i can accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` should be same as `optionKey` e.g. your optionKey is an `id` and therefore `value` should also be an `id` of the instance.
Try

```
value="${passedParameter?.id}"
```

Comment: this only is true, if `passedParameter` is of a similar type as the elements of `someList`